# I'm making a custom dynamic embed help command in discord.js how do I embed the command information?

Tags: discord.js, embed

The code works, it embeds when I do -help but if I do -help {command} it shows an unembedded text. How would I go about embedding the name, aliases, description, and cooldown (dynamically).

This is what I have tried.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'help',
  aliases: ['h'],
  description: 'A help Command',
  cooldown: 5,
  execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord) {
    const data = [];
    const { commands } = message.client;
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;

    if (!args.length) {
      const title = 'Here\'s a list of all my commands:';
      const description = data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));
      const footer = `You can send ${prefix}help [command name] to get info on a specific command!`;
      const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTitle(title)
        .setDescription(data)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(footer);
      return message.author.send(helpEmbed)
        .then(() => {
          if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
            message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
          message.reply(`it seems like I can't DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?`);
        });
    }
    const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
    const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

    if (!command) {
      return message.reply('that\'s not a valid command!');
    }
          
    data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);
          
    if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
    if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
    if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);
    if (command.cooldown) data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown} seconds`);        
          
    message.channel.send(data, { split: true });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are simply sending an array of strings, rather than an [embed object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed). To [create an embed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/embed), you can do one of the following:

**Use the [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) constructor:**

```js
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

const embed = new MessageEmbed();
// dynamically add data using MessageEmbed methods
if (someCondition) embed.addField("name", "value");
if (anotherCondition) embed.setDescription("description");
```

**Create an embed using an object:**

```js
const embed = {
  description: "",
  fields: []
};
// dynamically add data using basic JavaScript methods
if (someCondition) embed.fields.push({name: "name", value: "value"});
if (anotherCondition) embed.description = "description";
```

Check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) to see the methods you can use with the [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) class.

Another useful resource is this [Embed Visualizer](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/).